# Deploying Different WSO2 product as single carbon application project

Tags: wso2, business-process-management, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using `WSO2 DSS, ESB and BPS` for my project.
They are working fine in respective servers. But my idea is to integrate DSS, ESB & BPS into one car file(or some other deployment archive file) and thus making the deployment easier.

I have a `Carbon application project` created in `Developer studio` which has DSS project, ESB Config project, BPEL workflow and a Web application in it.
When I export it, it exports only the ESB & BPS and excludes Web application.
Is there a way to generate one deployment archive which would contain all the mentioned project? And is it possible to deploy a java application in WSO2 server since it has tomcat in it?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you verify wether the web application is included the Carbon Archive's pom.xml? Probably you haven't included your web application. Just double click and open the said file. There's a graphical UI which lets you choose the artifacts you want to be bundled in the CAR.

Comment: Yes. You are right. First I created my ESB application, then DSS and finally BPS. Those added in the pom.xml but the web application I created yesterday is not included in the pom.xml automatically. But wen give **mvn clean compile package** it is throwing me error that **some of the artifacts are not found** and not generating `.car` file. Also when I export from developer studio directly, the xml files are getting generated but not my project dependencies(*.jar files). Kindly help me on this.

Comment: Please add the error you got, and what kind of dependencies you are talking about. Is it the dependencies of WAR that should go in to WEB-INF/lib?

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy webapplications in WSO2 Application server. Refer [this](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Developing+and+Deploying+Different+Application+Types). There is a server role which is defined in the server and also in the CAR file for each deployable artifacts. So if you are going to use one server lets say application server with DSS,ESB and BPS installed you need to add DSS's ESB's and BPS's server roles so artifacts which has respective servers role can be deployed in bundled server. Please refer following for server role management.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AS510/Introduction+to+Server+Roles

Answer (score 1):

Q>
Is there a way to generate one deployment archive which would contain all the mentioned project?

Ans>> Yes. It is possible. Carbon Application Archive(CAR) file is the single deployable module to package all the above mentioned different artifacts type to a single deployable archive.

You can use either IDE or Maven to generate the CAR file for your artifacts. Please refer to [Dev Studio Documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Packaging+Artifacts+Into+Deployable+Archives) for more information.

Q> And is it possible to deploy a java application in WSO2 server since it has tomcat in it?

Ans>> You can deploy a Java application in WSO2 Application Server but in order to do that you need to convert your application to a Web-Services since WSO2 provides mechanism to expose your applications as Web Services. For that you can use either Axis2 Web Service or Jax-WS web-Service.

WSO2 Developer Studio supports creation of Axis2 Web-Services as well as Jax-WS web services. Please refer to [Axis2 Artifact](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+an+Axis2+Project) and [Jax-WS Artifact](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+JAX-WS+and+JAX-RS+Service+Projects) Documentation for more information.

Also if you have a Java based Web-Application, you may deploy that Web-Application in WSO2 Application Server and WSO2 Dev Studio supports [implementing Web-Applications](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DVS320/Creating+a+Web+Application) as well.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana